# Programmatically create a table of contents in the Parent wiki page with the titles of the child pages as content

Tags: wiki, confluence

I am creating child wiki pages under one single parent page using a python script using confluence cli. 
These appear as child pages at the bottom of the parent wiki page. 
The requirement is that I need to create a Table of Contents in the parent page. This should contain the titles of the child pages that are being created.
I am not able to find how to add this Table of Contents, any pointer on how to do this please? 
I am using confluence CLI for creating the wiki pages as follows:
confluence_cli = confluence.Client()
confluence_cli.add_page(parent-page-title, child-page-title, child-page-data)

What is the way to add a link to the child-page from within the parent-page?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Children Display macro to the parent page. This will list all children and even sub-children if desired.